# net.HTTPClient():request How to return a table

Tags: lua

I am using LUA in Fibaro Home Centre 2 and want to return a table array from within a `net.HTTPClient():request`, can anyone point me to a way of doing this?

Code Sample:

```
roomsArray = {}

-- Get the number of rooms and their names from the Heating Panel
local HC2 = net.HTTPClient();  
 HC2:request('http://127.0.0.1:11111/api/panels/heating', {
   success = function(resp)
    if resp.status == 200 then
      data = json.decode(resp.data)
      for k, v in pairs(data) do 
        table.insert(roomsArray,v.name)          
      end   
      for k, v in pairs(roomsArray) do fibaro:debug("Room index :" .. k .. ", room name is:" .. v) end -- This line works
    else
      fibaro:debug(resp.status)
    end
  end

})

for k, v in pairs(roomsArray) do fibaro:debug("Room index :" .. k .. ", room name is:" .. v) end -- this line produced nothing 
fibaro:debug(roomsArray[1]) -- debug output "nil"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
HC2:Get and HC2:PUT
response=HC2:GET("api/panels/heating")


HC2:PUT("api/panels/heating". response
)
```